# How can i hide Discount Code form checkout payment page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, xml, coupon

I tried to hide the Discount Code field from `checkout payment page`, but i can't find anything in xml files.

For `cart page`, i found this field in checkout_cart_index.xml, and i was able to hide like this:

```
 <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="cart/coupon.phtml"/>
                            <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.coupon" remove="true"/>
```

Does anyone know how this field it's add on the payment page? or from where i can deleted?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use below CSS for hiding discount block.

```
.checkout-index-index .payment-option._collapsible.opc-payment-additional.discount-code {
    display: none;
}
```

**Edit**

`app/code/vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

or

`app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

you can also remove discount block using '**checkout_index_index.xml**'

@Prashant is also correct;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Happy I found this - my colleague obviously used this to hide the field, and I had to re-enable it now :-)

Comment: What file do you put that CSS in @Chirag

Comment: @Supplement You can write in your custom global CSS file.

Comment: So this would be in like that same directory structure but inside web/css/global.css? Can you elaborate a bit more on this topic.. like the exact directory structure and would the name just be "global.css" which resides in whatever directory? @chirag

Comment: hi @chirag how to remove coupon code block from cart page?

Comment: add <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.coupon" remove="true" /> in checkout_cart_index.xml file

Comment: @chirag it hides in the cart page but in the payment page, it is still showing.

Comment: How to add discount coupan code on custom steps which i have created between shipping and payment methods will you please help @chirag

Comment: although xml solution looks valid, we can even hide coupon code with css as it is not mandatory field.

Comment: And if we want to disable it based on some helper function? is it possible?

Comment: Worked for me by adding it to my child theme default.xml.
Thanks for the info

Answer (score 9):

Add `checkout_index_index.xml` at your custom module `app/code/vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

Add below code to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">        
                                                                <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

In above code You find below code through this I have removed item discount :

```
<item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Also refer for more [information](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html#disable-a-component)

Comment: Note you can just put this in your theme's default.xml if you don't want to create a module.

Comment: This code worked for me in my child theme's default.xml, so an upvote to @PedroKTFC too. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

override checkout_cart_index.xml file

and last line remove coupon code block

Move from app/design/frontend/V/T/Magento_checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            .....
            .....
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.coupon" remove="true"/>



        </body>
    </page>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your theme's local.xml add the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layout>
    <checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <remove name="checkout.cart.coupon"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
</layout>
```

It will remove discount coupon.

Comment: it's for checkout payment page?  i think this it's for cart page, no checkout payment page

Comment: Themes no longer have a local.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this also to remove **Gift Card Options** from checkout page. Generally it appears below **discount coupon** section.

> app/design/frontend/Company/theme/Magento_GiftCardAccount/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">        
                                                            <item name="giftCardAccount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

> This is very important

```
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
  <item name="giftCardAccount" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </item>
  </item>
</item>
```

Comment: how to remove coupon code block from cart page?

Answer (score 0):

Add a file named "theme.xml" to app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/ and add this text:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.coupon" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```