# Magento 2 : <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.coupon" remove="true"/> being ignored

Tags: magento2, cart, blocks

If I comment out `<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="cart/coupon.phtml"/>`
in
`E:\Projects\Cupolas\app\design\frontend\tv_themevast_package\default\Magento_Checkout\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml` the discount code box does not show up.

But the correct way to do this is by adding `<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.coupon" remove="true"/>` in `E:\Projects\Cupolas\app\design\frontend\tv_themevast_package\default\Magento_Checkout\layout\checkout_index_index.xml` but when I both clear the cache and deploy (though overkill) my cart still shows the discount block.

What may I be missing?

Comment: this code `<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.coupon" remove="true"/>` you add your `Magento_Theme` folder in default.xml file

Comment: Thanks that did the trick actually

Comment: Hello @jasonhall0612 i added answer you check

Answer (score 0):

Use below CSS for hiding discount block.

```
.checkout-index-index .payment-option._collapsible.opc-payment-additional.discount-code {
    display: none;
}
```

**`Edit`**

**`app/code/vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`**

**or**

**`app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`**

you can also remove discount block using **`checkout_index_index.xml`**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">        
                                                            <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

And you Get more information check this link :-

**[How can i hide Discount Code form checkout payment page in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159986/how-can-i-hide-discount-code-form-checkout-payment-page-in-magento-2)**

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: you helped answer accept the answer so useful other community thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You need to create

```
checkout_cart_index.xml
```

At the following location like this :

```
E:\Projects\Cupolas\app\design\frontend\tv_themevast_package\default\Magento_Checkout\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml
```

And then add this code into that one.

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.coupon" remove="true"/>
```