# How can i hide Discount Code form Payment page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I have seen many articles on how to hide the discount code on the cart page and I was able to do that, but my attempts to hide the discount code on the PAYMENT page seems to be illusive for me. What is the correct way to hide the Discount Code option on the payment page.

TIA

Jason

Comment: I actually ended up doing this solution: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/160012/90332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That are Two methods like :-

**`Method 1`** :- you want to remove using css try this code your custom css file.

```
.checkout-index-index .payment-option._collapsible.opc-payment-additional.discount-code {
    display: none;
}
```

**`Method 2`** :- you don't want to hide discount code using css. So try you xml file way

**`app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">        
                                                            <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

After you change run some basic command :-

```
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

you want to get more information :-

**[How can i hide Discount Code form checkout payment page in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159986/how-can-i-hide-discount-code-form-checkout-payment-page-in-magento-2/160012#160012)**

**`THANKS.`**